# MYSQL Count - Return 0 if null

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Here's my query:

```
select COUNT(*) as total, COUNT(distinct user) as unique 
FROM table 
WHERE uristem in ('/example/', '/example/', '/example/', '/example/') 
      and time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)' 
group by uristem;
```

Should look like this

```
100 50
25  50
0   0
100 35
```

But if there is no count, it looks like this (missing)

```
100 50
40  50
100 35
```

How can I fill in 0's instead?

Comment: add some example records please.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a table with the uri stems in then something ugly like

```
Select
  u.uristem,
  count(t.uristem),
  count(distinct t.user) as unique
From (
    Select '/example1/' As uristem
    Union All Select '/example2/'
    Union All Select '/example3/'
    Union All Select '/example4/'
  ) u
    Left Outer Join
  table t
    On u.uristem = t.uristem And
    t.time > Date_Sub(Now(), Interval 24 Hour)
 Group By
   u.uristem
```

Should do it

Comment: Hey @Laurence, I had roughly the same answer as you but then realised - there's a where condition on t which breaks the benefits of the outer join.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Oh, just moving that to part of the on condition will fix that, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
select COUNT(t.uristem) as total
, COUNT(distinct t.user) as unique 
FROM 
    (
        select uristem, user
        from table
        where time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
    ) t
right outer join 
(
    select '/example/' x
    union select '/example/'
    union select '/example/'
    union select '/example/'
) y
on t.uristem = y.x
group by y.x;
```